# .zip file upload Spring

Tags: java, spring, request, zip

I have a Multipart file upload request. The file is a zip file- .zip format.
How do i unzip this file? 
I need to populate a Hashmap with each entry's filepath and filecontent.

```
HashMap<filepath, filecontent>
```

The code I have so far:

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipName);
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(fis));
 ZipEntry entry;

 while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            int size;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            FileOutputStream fos =
                    new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            BufferedOutputStream bos =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(fos, buffer.length);

            while ((size = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        }

        zis.close();
        fis.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using FileOutputStream, use ByteArrayOutputStream to capture the output.  Then, before executing the 'close' operation on the BAOS, use the 'toByteArray()' method on it to get the contents as a byte array (or, use 'toString()').  So, your code should look like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, byte[]> test(String zipName) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, byte[]> returnValue = new HashMap<>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipName);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(fis));
    ZipEntry entry;

    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

        int size;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos =
                new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos =
                new BufferedOutputStream(baos, buffer.length);

        while ((size = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        returnValue.put(entry.getName(),baos.toByteArray());
    }

    zis.close();
    fis.close();
    return returnValue;
}
```